# Find minimum sort required to order (no swapping)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I don't know exactly how to solve this problem. Given an array let's say with 4 items (can be any length).

How to order the array but without swapping. So for instance the array [4,3,2,1,0] needs to become [0,1,2,3,4] but only by shifting. So 0 at the end of the array needs to be moved to the beginning but only by shifting it so.  [4,3,2,1,0] -> [4,3,2,0,1]->[4,3,0,2,1] etc to [0,4,3,2,1]. etc

Each shift needs to be counted. What I would like to find is the minimum amount of shifts required to order the array? Seems like there would be an algorithm for this but not sure what it is.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This is the algorithm: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-swaps-sort-adjacent-swapping-allowed/

Comment: why isn't [1,0] -> [0,1] considered a swap? If you mean adjacent swap, the minimum number of steps required is of order O(n^2), because that's the Cayley distance.

Comment: If there are 2 elements then the shifting becomes a swap. So what I meant was for an array [4,3,2,1,0] -> can't become [0,3,2,1,4] with one move/shift...

Comment: @Chrispresso Thanks. That was what I was looking for but I can't mark it as an answer since it's a comment?

Comment: u may [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) the answer here, with cited credit to the commenter. So it can benefit others, and make the answer independent). Optionally, you upvote the commenter other answers on this site (to credit the commenter.)